# 301 Redirect with .htaccess to a new domain with editing some specific links

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I am trying to move my whole website through .htaccess doing this

```
 #Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newdomain/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Some of the links from the old website are not exactly the same of the new website, so I should manually edit this rule to make an exception from olddomain/link to newdomain/new-link

I tried the rules but it didn't work.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure your custom rules are written **before** your global redirection and are tagged Last [R=301,L]

exemple :

```
 Rewrite oldURI https://newdomain/newCustomURI [R=301,L]
```

Also, try in a fresh (private ? or new ) browser window : in some browsers , http redirection are cached

Comment: I tried to insert the rule like this

#Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine on
 Rewrite /oldlink https://newdomain/newCustomURI [R=301,L]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newdomain/$1 [R=301,L]

But it didn't work, maybe there is something that I didn't write?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved like this

```
    #Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /old/link/ https://newdomain/new-link
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newdomain/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks.

Ciao.